# Webpack eslint-loader ignore .eslintrc parser

Tags: webpack, eslint, eslint-loader

I'm having an issue with `webpack`, specifically `eslint-loader`.

I have a JS file, with code like:

```js
class Test {

    MyProp = "MyValue"

}

export default Test;
```

Initially, when I called `npx eslint .`, I got:

```
D:\repro\src\main\js\index.js
  3:12  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =
```

I've read somewhere I had to add `"parser": "babel-eslint"` to .eslintrc for some reason.

That did fix the issue with `npx eslint`, but I still have the issue with `npx webpack`:

```
ERROR in ./src/main/js/index.js 3:11
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:11)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js
```

I must have forgot some configuration somewhere, but I can't seem to find where.

To reproduce this, consider this repo:

https://github.com/slacaze/webpack-eslint-issue

1. `npm install`
2. `npx eslint` => No error (.eslintrc.json uses `babel-eslint` as parser)
3. `npx webpack` => Error as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not that your eslint is failing, it is that this source is not packable without running it through babel. You need to use babel-loader to actually transpile your code, estlint-loader is merely checking your syntax.

First, you need to add the babel-loader as shown here:
https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/

Install:

```
npm install -D babel-loader @babel/core @babel/preset-env webpack
```

Then configure (remember the order is bottom to top so put this above the eslint entry):

```
    {
        test: /\.?js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
        }
    },
```

Also, classProperties is not enabled by default so you'll need that as well:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Install:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties
```

Configure by adding a .babelrc:

```
{
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
}
```

As in this updated version:

https://github.com/dpwrussell/webpack-eslint-issue